# Videos won't autoplay on Chrome and Firefox

Tags: html, google-chrome, firefox, video, autoplay

I have several pages where the embedded video from vimeo should autoplay at it doesn't on Chrome and Firefox.

This is the code I have tried and it doesn't work. I cannot seem to figure out what is wrong and how I can fix it.

```
 <iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/335356647?autoplay=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" webkitallowfullscreen="" mozallowfullscreen="" allowfullscreen="" allow=autoplay data-ready="true"></iframe>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Annotate the `<iframe>` Like so:

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/335356647?autoplay=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; fullscreen"></iframe>
```

It's called "Iframe delegation" and is described here: https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try with this

```
<iframe src="https://player.vimeo.com/video/335356647?autoplay=1&title=0&byline=0&portrait=0" frameborder="0" allow="autoplay; encrypted-media"></iframe>
```